# ChartJS - ignore labels

Tags: charts, chart.js

I am using ChartJS and need a chart like this: https://tppr.me/OE08p
Meaning it should ignore 4 of the labels (flexibility, external, stability, internal) and connect the dots from the other 4 labels (like the red lines show on the screenshot).

Can I ignore these 4 labels data-wise somehow, but keep them?

Other chart packages/solutions are welcome, if it is not possible in chartjs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **highchart.js** library, see:

- docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/polar-chart
- example: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider

with these options:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        connectNulls: true
    }
}
```

and filtering data with map function like below (just for example):

```
data.map(filter)

<omissis>

function filter(item, index) {
    if (index==2)
        return null;
    else
        return item;
}
```

here is a jsfiddle showing this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/w6ozog1c/

or a snippet here:

```js
// original data
var data1 = [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
 data2 = [50000, 39000, 42000, 31000, 26000, 14000];

var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Budget vs spending',
        x: -80
    },
    pane: {
        size: '80%'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support',
                'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 70,
        layout: 'vertical'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Allocated Budget',
        data: data1.map(filter),  // filtered data
        pointPlacement: 'on',
        color: 'red'
    }, {
        name: 'Actual Spending',
        data: data2,
        pointPlacement: 'on',
        color: 'green'
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            connectNulls: true // connects also null value (bypassing)
        }
    }
});

var filterOn = true;

$('#button').click(function () {
 filterOn = !filterOn;
 if (filterOn)
    chart.series[0].setData(data1.map(filter));
  else
   chart.series[0].setData(data1);
});

// filter function with your criteria
function filter(item, index) {
    if (index==2)
     return null;
    else
     return item;
}
```

```css
.highcharts-grid-line {
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<button id="button">Toggle filter (ignoring a point in red serie)</button>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```